# Install a Sublime Text Package from Linux command line (in Sublime Text 3 using Package Control)

Tags: 16.04, command-line, package-management, software-installation, sublime-text

I know how one may install Sublime text packages within Sublime text (it is well described at https://packagecontrol.io/docs/usage ).

But I am looking for way to do it automatically, without a manual installation (for example after system reinstall).

Is it feasible?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the answer you are looking for. But what about just backing up your ~/.config/sublime-text-3 folder and restoring it again? This will at least work for a system reinstall.

Comment: I will not accept for now as in my case main point of reinstall is to reset all what I tweaked and changed, and apply what I consider to be verified changes. So only upvote for now.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19531651

This seems to be exactly what you want. Just modify the content of `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings` with packages you want and restart Sublime to see the miracle.

Remark: When you restart Sublime it could go frozen due to a huge pile of packages it has to download